# How do I adjust my table and image in to same page

Tags: tables

I am new to this latex and getting hard time in adjusting my table and image in the same page. I found a way to add image and table in the same page but it adds some unnecessary words in the generated pdf. If any one can help me how i can remove that words from PDF. Here is the screen shot of the pdf that I generate using the below.[image]

```
\phantom{~}\noindent

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}{p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}}
\hline
Feature   Extraction                         & Feature selection                     & classifier & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{400BY400} & \multirow{3}{*}{X}      & SVM-RBF    & 79    & 79     & 76 \\ \cline{3-6} 

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 79   & 81      & 69  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & Rf         & 72  & 71     & 68  \\ \cline{2-6} 



\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{Test_trace}          & SVM-RBF    & 63    &61   & 52 \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                                                

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 66    & 62     & 46  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 64    & 63     & 58  \\ \cline{2-6} 


\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{SVFS}          & SVM-RBF    & 78    &73    & 76 \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                                                

                                             &                                       & KNN        &78    & 79     & 66  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 80    & 75     & 71  \\ \cline{2-6} 

\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{PCA}          & SVM-RBF    & 58    & 56     & 49 \\ \cline{3-6}                                   

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 59    & 56     & 56  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 56    & 51     & 59  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{Univariate selection}   & SVM-RBF    & 71   & 70    & 59  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                                                 

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 71    & 72    & 55  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 70    & 67     & 63 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\caption{$8080$ Image size } 
%\label{CH2-beta-ij}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=.9\textwidth]{pic5.JPG}
        \caption{$$}
        \label{Smooth}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you like to achieve something like this:

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{$8080$ Image size }
\label{tab:CH2-beta-ij}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{5em}|
                 >{\raggedright}m{5em}|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
Feature Extraction                         
    & Feature selection                     
        & classifier 
            & Accuracy 
                & Precision 
                    & Recall \\     \hline
\multirow{13}{*}{400BY400} 
    & \multirow{3}{*}{X}      
        & SVM-RBF   & 79    & 79    & 76    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & KNN       & 79    & 81    & 69    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & Rf        & 72    & 71    & 68    \\  \cline{2-6}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{ some text}
        & KNN       & 66    & 62    & 46    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & RF        & 64    & 63    & 58    \\  \cline{2-6}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{SVFS}          
        & SVM-RBF   & 78    & 73    & 76    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & KNN       &78     & 79    & 66    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & RF        & 80    & 75    & 71    \\  \cline{2-6}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{PCA}          
        & SVM-RBF   & 58    & 56    & 49    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & KNN       & 59    & 56    & 56    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & RF        & 56    & 51    & 59    \\  \cline{2-6}
\multirow{7}{*}{}                            
    & \multirow{3}{=}{Univariate selection}   
        & SVM-RBF   & 71    & 70    & 59    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & KNN       & 71    & 72    & 55    \\  \cline{3-6}
    &   & RF        & 70    & 67    & 63    \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

    \vspace{2\baselineskip} % <---- or some other vertical space 
\includegraphics[height=6cm,width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{my beautiful duck}
\label{fig:Smooth}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** added is bigger space between table an image

Comment: I did in same way but my table and image are so closed how do I add space between table and image such that image will have have some space after table and both will remain on same page?

Comment: @KiranRaoo, sorry, I do not understand what you like. Bigger distance between table and image? If yes, than replace `\medskip` with  `\vspace{<desired vertical space>}`.

Comment: yes I got it thank you.

Comment: @KiranRaoo, I edit my answer and add bigger vertical space between table and figure. See added comment in code. If now answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept it by clicking on the check mark at top left side of the answer.